# Available Android themes for apps?

Tags: android

Are there any (archive of) themes/styles readily available that I can just use when I develop an app for Android, beside the ones that comes distributed with the Android SDK?

Comment: Pls share if u have answer ....

Comment: Sorry, till date I still haven't found any such resources. I will answer this post if I come across one.

Comment: If Possible can u share ur theme , if u have made :D

Comment: I have made a theme, but it is far from complete, so I am not comfortable sharing it yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Theme.Light or Theme.Dark that android gives for apply on activities.

There are very few. You can check them here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html . They start with Theme.something

You can use them like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: As I wrote in the questions, I am looking for other themes besides the ones that are bundled with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You mean for wireframing?
There are some like these:

http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/04/ZURB-releases-new-android-gingerbread-stencils-for-designers.php

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools

http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/01/illustrator-template-toolbox-for-web-mobile-and-app-developers/

Comment: No, I don't mean for wireframing.